# DTO not working with custom decorator in NestJS

Tags: node.js, typescript, nestjs, dto, typescript-decorator

i'm trying to use DTO near a custom decorator inside a controller in NestJS to validate the body. I'm making the request using a multipart/form so i have to parse the data from string to JSON. Then i have to validate that JSON using a DTO, but this doesn't work. Can someone help me with this issue? Here's the code of the controller.

```
@Post('flows')
@UseInterceptors(FilesInterceptor('file'))
async createFlow(@BodyParser('data') data: CreateFlowDto, @User() user: UserType, @UploadedFiles() file: any) {

  const flowId =  await this.approvalService.createFlow(data, file, user)

  return {
    id: flowId
  }

}
```

This is the custom decorator called "BodyParser".

```
export const BodyParser = createParamDecorator(
  (data: string, ctx: ExecutionContext) => {
    const dataToParse = ctx.switchToHttp().getRequest().body[data];

        try {            
            return JSON.parse(dataToParse)


        } catch (error) {
            throw new BadRequestException('The JSON is invalid');
        }

  },
    
);
```

The DTO works fine, the custom decorator parse the string into JSON
correctly but if i use this decorator, the controller doesn't make the validation, how can i fix this?

Comment: By "make it into validation" are you meaning validation via the `ValidationPipe` from `@nestjs/common`?

Answer (score 2):

Stumbled upon the same issue, if you're using `ValidationPipe`, turns out that you have to set `validateCustomDecorators: true` or use custom pipes (i.e `@BodyParser('data', CustomValidator)`).

```
app.useGlobalPipes(new ValidationPipe({ validateCustomDecorators: true }));
```

References:

- [ValidationPipe not run for Custom Decorators · Issue #2010 · nestjs/nest (github.com)](https://github.com/nestjs/nest/issues/2010)
- [feature(common): add option to allow validation of custom decorators by TheNoim · Pull Request #2304 · nestjs/nest (github.com)](https://github.com/nestjs/nest/pull/2304)

Comment: Holy sh*t! That's exactly what I was looking for. Thank you boss!